# Resuming large file on uGet

Tags: downloads, uget

Can uGet download a large file around 5 GB without failing?

How to increase uGet download speed?

Comment: uGet can handle whatever size it needs to download like any other similar tool. Speed and stability has to do with the network, not the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, UGet can download such a file without problems, if your network connection is reliable. However, if your network is not reliable, or your internet connection drops half way through the download, you can still finish downloading the entire file, if the server you're downloading from [supports resuming incomplete downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084677/determine-if-server-supports-resume-get-request) (most do these days).

To increase the download speed (by downloading multiple pieces of the file at the same time) and potentially make the download even more reliable, you can [install the aria2 plugin](http://ugetdm.com/downloads-ubuntu#aria2) (by typing `sudo apt install aria2` in a terminal, and then enabling it in the UGet settings)

That said, is the file available to download vis BitTorrent too ? If that's the case you should probably use that, as you'll get possibly faster speed and more reliability, as BitTorrent is designed to handle resuming, unreliable connections, and so on.

Comment: i recently install aria2, after that i change plugin setting on uget to aria2, but when i save the configuration suddenly uget has stopped working. how i fix this problem?

Comment: @Sankarea Are you using the uget version from the Ubuntu repositories, or did you install it from their PPA ? I suggest you try the latest version version from the PPA, as the version Ubuntu has may be a bit outdated. What do you mean with "uget has stopped working" ? Do you see any error messages ?

Comment: yes,i already installed stable version from their PPA . Uget stopped working is like force close on android, but when i see the directory download i see some file with .aria2 . is the download resumed?

Comment: @Sankarea Yes, the files ending in `.aria2` is the data needed to resume downloading, so resuming should work. If you still can't launch uget, what do you see when you run `uget-gtk` in a terminal ?